# Изменение выделенного текста в форме при событии клаватуры

Tags: javascript, html

Хочу сделать такую плюшку. Когда ты выделяешь текст в поле и жмешь кнопку "2", то вначале выделенного вставляется <p>     и в конце соответственно </p>  Возможно ли такое реализовать ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ответ - window.getSelection()

```
document.onkeydown = function(e){
if (e.keyCode==50) {
    var p= document.createElement("p");
    p.style.fontWeight = "bold";

    if (window.getSelection) {
    var s = window.getSelection();
    if (s.rangeCount) {
        var range = s.getRangeAt(0).cloneRange();
        range.surroundContents(p);
        s.removeAllRanges();
        s.addRange(range);
    }
}
}

}
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Rwexc/

Comment: @vkovalchuk88 Проблема в том, что он вставляет перед textarea DOM el <P>, а мне надо чтобы в value textarea вставляло текст